# selecting a certain column value from looping in ienumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a result of IEnumerable from a stored procedure and i am looping through the results inorder to get the value of a column(GUID). I am unsure of how to go about on getting the Guid column from my results set in the foreach loop

this is what i have:

```
var results = GetGuids(instId);
foreach (var item in results)
{

}

public IEnumerable GetGuids(int id)
        {
            using (SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("StoredProc"))
            {
                _command.Connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
                _command.Connection.Open();
                _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", id);

                return _command.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
```

Comment: @CamBruce how can i get the Guid column from my results in the foreach loop

Comment: This will get you pointed in the right direction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Comment: @CamBruce not really sure if this is returning the same type of what i am looking for.

Comment: @GrantWinney returns rows in the stored procs which contain 3 columns, id, level and guid - i am interested in getting the value in the guid column.

Comment: @GrantWinney they are DbDataRecord objects, but it's the non-generic IEnumerable, so it may just as well be IEnumerable<Object>, because the linq extension methods don't exist at all for the basic non-generic IEnumerable. Actually, it's worse, because you could at least cast IEnumerable<Object>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use most of the normal linq extension methods directly on the non-generic IEnumerable... but you can call [`.Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) to make it an `IEnumerable<T>`. At that point, things get easier:

```
public IEnumerable<Guid> GetGuids(int id)
{
    using (SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("StoredProc"))
    {
        _command.Connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
        _command.Connection.Open();
        _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _command.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  id;

            return _command.ExecuteReader()
                  .Cast<DbDataRecord>()
                  .Select(r => (Guid)r["GuidColumn"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `Item` coming from? i have it throwing compile error that it doesn't contain a definition.

Comment: My mistake, fixed now. C# uses that as an indexer instead. I had just answered a similar question in VB, and VB uses .Item("")

Answer (score 0):

You need to produce the results yourself from the `SqlDataReader`

```
 var results = GetGuids(instId);
    foreach (var item in results)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<Guid> GetGuids(int id)
            {
                using (SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("StoredProc"))
                {
                    _command.Connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
                    _command.Connection.Open();
                    _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", id);

    var guids = new List<Guid>();

                   using (SqlDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader())
                   {
                     while (reader.Read()
                     {
                    guids.Add( (Guid)reader["GuidColumn"]);
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This forces the entire result set into RAM, rather than iterating over one result at a time like you would expect from a DataReader.