# casting IEnumerable doesn't have definition for item

Tags: c#, ienumerable

i am trying to return results from IEnumerable and i am interested in one column which contains what i am looking for. But with what i have based on a member's suggested answer [selecting a certain column value from looping in ienumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957832/selecting-a-certain-column-value-from-looping-in-ienumerable) i am getting a compile error:

```
public IEnumerable<Guid> GetGuids(int id)
{
    using (SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand("StoredProc"))
    {
        _command.Connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
        _command.Connection.Open();
        _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", id);

            return _command.ExecuteReader()
                  .Cast<DbDataRecord>()
                  .Select(r => (Guid)r.Item["GuidColumn"]);
    }
}
```

Error: that DbDataRecord does not contain a definition for `Item`.
How do i go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it should be:

```
return _command.ExecuteReader()
               .Cast<DbDataRecord>()
               .Select(r =>(Guid) r["GuidColumn"]);
```

Comment: Just tried this and got this: `The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'StoredProc', database 'Name', schema 'dbo'.`

Comment: @Masriyah, Well, make sure the account that you're executing the stored procedure with (look at the connection string) has the appropriate permissions to do so.